# Python determine a blank column in a csv

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I'm making a config generating template in python, and it all works this far apart from my `if row == ''` section.

So I'm trying to check if a csv has blank data for the column BT and, if it's blank, remove any line that has the variable `$BTSUB` in it.

It's not working currently and I'm presuming it's because a csv empty column is not seen as '', does anyone know what it is seen as?

Also does anyone see any ways to improve what I have done below? (it's my first script)

Thanks
Alex

```python
import csv
import os
with open('Data/ShowroomData.csv', 'rt') as Data:
    SR = csv.DictReader(Data, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in SR:
        # if you were to print just `row`, you would get a dictionary

        # set config file path
        folder  = 'Data/'
        filename = row['Host']
        path = folder + '/' + filename
        file = path + '/STR-' + filename + '-RTR-01.txt'
        # check if path exists if not make path
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs (path)
        # Read in the config file
        R1 = None
        with open('Data/STR-RTR-01.txt', 'r') as R1Template, open(file, 'w') as configfile:
            R1 = R1Template.read()

            # Replace the target string
            R1 = R1.replace('$STR', row['Host'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$IP', row['Subnet'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$DMVPN-DSL', row['DMVPN-DSL'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$DMVPN-4G', row['DMVPN-4G'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$BGPASNO', row['BGPAS'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$KCIP', row['KCIP'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$WRIP', row['WRIP'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$LOIP', row['Loopback'])              
            R1 = R1.replace('$DSL-USER', row['DSL-USER'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$DSL-PASS', row['DSL-PASS'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$Date', row['InstallDate'])

            if row['BT'] == (''):
                for line in R1:
                    if '$BTSUB' not in line:
                        # Write file without Static Routes
                        configfile.write(line)
            else:
                R1 = R1.replace('$BTSUB', row['BT'])
                # Write the file 
                configfile.write(R1)
```

EDIT: debug output

```
{'DMVPN-DSL': '79', 'DSL-PASS': '', 
 'Host': 'TEST', 'DSL-USER': '',
 'InstallDate': '', 'BGPAS': 'XXX', 'BT': '', 
 'Loopback': '172.X.X.X', 'KCIP': '172.XX.X.X', 
 'WRIP': '172.X.X.X', 'Location': 'Test', 
 'DMVPN-4G': '162', 'Subnet': '137'
}
```

Comment: Did you try `if not row['BT'].strip():` ?

Comment: just tried it, still no go, the lines are still in there

Comment: Can you add the output of `if not row['BT'].strip(): print(row)` please

Comment: added it to the post

Comment: So the problem does not come from the blank condition but from this one: `if '$BTSUB' not in line:`

Comment: I see, what could not be working there? what im trying to do is, if the BT column is empty remove any line with $BTSUB in it and write the file, if its not empty, replace it with the value

Comment: I added an explanation in my answer. Comment there if it's not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem does not come from `if row['BT'] == (''):` but from your loop: `for line in R1:`
When you do this:

```
R1 = R1Template.read()
```

R1 becomes a string. And when you loop on a string you get:

```
In [69]: for line in "abcd":
   ....:     print(line)
a
b
c
d
```

Therefore this condition will never be true (because `line` is just one character):

```
if '$BTSUB' not in line:
```

There're several way to fix this, the quickest, given your code structure is to change your `for` statement:

```
for line in R1.split('\n'): # If it's unix-like line endings
```

Although it's probably not the most efficient way.

If you need to keep the line return:

```
configfile.write("{}\n".format(line))
```

Or use a `list` and `writelines()`

Comment: ok that worked, but then it put all my config on 1 line after it did it, so my router will not be able to read it,  also i cant proof it to make sure if its ok, is there anyway to put the line breaks back in after weve checked it?

Comment: TypeError: write() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given), would it be more effecient to use split lines or a list?

Comment: I made a typo it's `.format()`. Yes there's a lot of performance improvements to be made in this script, but I think it'd be better to do that as another topic :)

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the contents of the template file using `R1Template.read()`. This puts the complete contents (all lines concatenated) into the variable `R1`. The `for` loop over `R1` then iterates over this string character by character, so the substring `$BTSUB` will never be found inside any of these one-character strings.

There are two possible solutions: either you read the template line by line, iterating over the file object `R1Template`, and apply the replacements to each line separately; or you keep reading the template as a whole and iterate its lines after all the replacing has been done; the list of lines will be `R1.splitlines()`.